# SQL Using results of query to create another table

Tags: mysql

```
(SELECT childinfo.first,childinfo.last,COUNT(clubinfo.club) AS clubs_per_student FROM clubinfo
LEFT JOIN childinfo
ON childinfo.child_id=clubinfo.child_id
GROUP BY concat(studentinfo.first,' ',studentinfo.last)
)
```

Above is the query that I have written to combine the tables childinfo (containing the columns child_id, first name, and last name) and clubinfo (containing columns child_id and club). The above query would produce a table that is something like this:

```
first     |     last     |     sports_per_child
Sally     |     Jones    |            2
Phil      |     Jones    |            1
Jane      |     Doe      |            1
John      |     Doe      |            1
```

What I am looking to do is use the results of that query to produce a report of the total number of students who are in a particular number of clubs. So, for example, the table above would produce a report that there are 3 students that are in 1 club and 1 student that is in 2 clubs.

Any ideas on how to write a query that uses my previously written query as a subquery to accomplish this?

Comment: from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) `CREATE TABLE bar (m INT) SELECT n FROM foo;`

Comment: I would certainly caution against using report tables on the fly. Can you explain why it is necessary if that is what I am reading into your question. If you want an example with a join let me know

Comment: Are you asking why is it necessary to do what I am trying to do or why I am trying to use the results of a subquery? If your question is the latter, it's because the original tables do not provide a count of how many sports each child participates in and I need this info in order to find the total number of children who participate in a certain number of sports. I am not sure if this is the best method as I am a beginner in MySQL

Comment: I was just trying to make sure I was not misunderstanding

Comment: That's perfectly understandable. I apologize if I sounded rude there - was just trying to be clear!

Comment: It is very common when you are starting with sql to think "It I only had a table of just this" ... we have all been there, and still are day-to-day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get a count and group by sports_per_child:

```
SELECT sports_per_child, count(*) FROM
(subquery) AS S
group by sports_per_child
```

Comment: When I use this syntax, I get the following: "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @Bob See the update, need an alias for the subquery.